# Undefined reference to standard library functions in plib

Tags: c, gcc, calloc, xc32, mplab-x-5.50

xc32 v2.41 or older working ok with plibs but the latest version of xc32

```
#include <plib.h>

int main() {

}
```

generating this error :

> "C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.00\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"
> -mprocessor=32MX664F128L -o dist/default/production/led.X.production.elf
> build/default/production/main.o -DXPRJ_default=default
> -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1,--no-code-in-dinit,--no-dinit-in-serial-mem,-Map="dist/default/production/led.X.production.map",--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml
> -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.00/packs/Microchip/PIC32MX_DFP/1.5.259"
> nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:140: recipe for target
> 'dist/default/production/led.X.production.hex' failed make[2]: Leaving
> directory 'C:/Users/Embedded
> Web/OneDrive/Documents/Mplax/v6.0/ledTest/led.X'
> nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:91: recipe for target '.build-conf'
> failed make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/Embedded
> Web/OneDrive/Documents/Mplax/v6.0/ledTest/led.X'
> nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
> c:\program
> files\microchip\xc32\v4.00\bin\bin\gcc\pic32mx\8.3.1........\bin/pic32m-ld.exe:
> c:/program
> files/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/bin/../../lib/gcc/pic32mx/8.3.1/../../../../pic32mx/lib\libmchp_peripheral_32MX664F128L.a(eth_descriptors_add_lib.o):
> in function `EthDescriptorsAdd': /home/mwmann/work/pic32-plib/peripheral/eth/source/_eth_dcpt_lists.h:(.text.EthDescriptorsAdd+0x64): undefined reference to` calloc' c:\program
> files\microchip\xc32\v4.00\bin\bin\gcc\pic32mx\8.3.1........\bin/pic32m-ld.exe:
> /home/mwmann/work/pic32-plib/peripheral/eth/source/_eth_dcpt_lists.h:(.text.EthDescriptorsAdd+0x124):
> undefined reference to `calloc'
>
> Info: Loading file: ./C:/Program
> Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.00/packs/Microchip/PIC32MX_DFP/1.5.259/xc32/32MX664F128L/p32MX664F128L.ld
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 255 exit status make[2]: ***
> [dist/default/production/led.X.production.hex] Error 255 make[1]: ***
> [.build-conf] Error 2 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
>
> BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)

How do I fix this, Thanks

Comment: What code are you trying to compile? Looks like C code, if yes, please add corresponding C tag and also include your code.

Comment: I added a test code snippet, but this problem is not related to c

Comment: This looks like a C snippet, why do you say it's not related to C? Also, you seem to be calling GCC compiler for xc32.

Comment: `/home/mwmann/work/pic32-plib/peripheral/eth/source/_eth_dcpt_lists.h` seems to be using/calling calloc somewhere but doesn't include the header file for calloc.

Comment: I don't have permission to modify the plib files but in the older version, there is no issue with the path or something like that

Comment: You can compare new and old files to see what has changed. Or maybe if the library has its release notes, the changes are mentioned there.

Comment: ok let me check, but the xc32 compiler is updated to the v4.00, not plibs